# jQuery drop down menu shows child of child too

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have this jQuery dropdown menu in Wordpress and I have a parent menu tab, then a child menu tab and then a child child menu tab.

When I hover my parent tab, my (first) child tabs appear, but the second child tabs too.

This is my jQuery code. I think that the problem is that in de first function the "ul.sub-menu" get slideToggle but that he do this for the other "ul-sub_menu" too. So I think I need the specify that he only takes the first ul-sub-menu and not the "deeper" ones. But I don't know how to do this? So can someone help me with this?

I made a jsfiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/6jKn7/

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#header_inner .menu-header-container ul li").hover(function() {
        $(this).find("a").toggleClass('hover');
        $("ul.sub-menu", this).slideToggle(50);
    });

    $("#header_inner .menu-header-container ul li ul li").hover(function() {
        $("ul.sub-menu", this).slideToggle(50);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to show/hide the descendants of the current element and its siblings.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#header_inner .menu-header-container ul li").hover(function () {
        $(this).find("a").toggleClass('hover');
        $(this).siblings().children(".sub-menu").hide();
        $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideToggle(50);        
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/b64sK/

Answer (score 1):

You should be using different class for nested `ul` . using  `$("ul.sub-menu")` will also affect inner dom which is sub sub menu.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jKn7/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
$("ul.sub-menu", this)
```

Take apply toggle to all ul.sub-menu of this, to any level.
If you want just to apply it to the first match, you can add .first after the selector.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#header_inner .menu-header-container ul li").hover(function () {
        $(this).find("a").toggleClass('hover');
        $("ul.sub-menu", this).first().slideToggle(50); //here
    });

    $("#header_inner .menu-header-container ul li ul li").hover(function () {
        $("ul.sub-menu", this).slideToggle(50);
    });
});
```

This would fix the problem, but I think the best solution would be to create different classes for each level of submenu.
And overall, I would definitely do this with pure CSS rather than with jQuery, since performances would be really better.

Comment: I have tried .first() earlier but that doesn't give the right result. But how would you tackle it with CSS then?

Comment: Try to Google "pure css dropdown menu" and you will find tons of examples like this http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

Comment: You should play with hover pseudo-selector.